# multiple kivy drop down

Tags: python, kivy

So I'm trying to write a simple code using the kivy framework, my code looks through a dictionary for a certain value that tell my code at a later stage which dictionary values need to be outputted as a drop down menu and which dict values just need to be outputted as a regular label and text input. Now the problem lies when the dictionary I am looking through describes more than one value that need to be a drop down. How i want the drop down to work is when a value is selected in the drop down the button that triggers the drop down must change text, to the text of the button that was clicked. Here is the code, I decided to write a simpler version for readabily. I wanted to type this underneath the code but i really suck at writing questions on stack Over Flow. The code you about to look at creates two buttons(that trigger drop downs), One named group 0 and another named group 1, however when i click the one of the drop down buttons under group 0, the group 1 text attribute changes, but I want to actually change the text attribute of the group 0 button. I have a rep of not making sense when i explain so let me know if you need clarity, any help would be appreciated.

```
from kivy.app import App
```

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

test_floatie = FloatLayout()
# We wanna create 2 button that trigger a drop down
i = 0

# The loop that creates the two buttons
while i < 2:

# Create a drop down
    dropdown = DropDown()
    for index in range(10):

        # Creating our button
        btn = Button(text="Button"+str(index), size_hint_y=None, height=44)

        # Sending button info to dropdown select function
        btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))

        # Closing drop down after selection
        btn.bind(on_release=dropdown.dismiss)

        # Adding buttons to the drop down
        dropdown.add_widget(btn)

    # Simple if statement for positioning
    if i == 0:
        position = "left"
    else:
        position = "right"

    # The button that triggers the drop down
    dropButton = Button(text="Group"+str(i), size_hint=(0.4, 0.3), pos_hint={"top":1, position:1})
    print(dropButton)

    # Binding the button to a function that triggers the drop down 
    dropButton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

    # Using the drop down select function to change the text of the button that triggers the drop down
    dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(dropButton, "text", x))

    test_floatie.add_widget(dropButton)

    i = i +1

# Running la app
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return test_floatie

MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified your code a little:

```py
from functools import partial

test_floatie = FloatLayout()
# We wanna create 2 button that trigger a drop down


def select(drop_button, text, btn):
    drop_button.text = text


# The loop that creates the two buttons
for position in ["left", "right"]:
    # The button that triggers the drop down
    dropButton = Button(text="Group " + position, size_hint=(0.4, 0.3),
                        pos_hint={"top": 1, position: 1})

    # Create a drop down
    dropdown = DropDown()
    for index in range(10):
        # Creating our button
        btn = Button(text=position + str(index), size_hint_y=None, height=44)

        # Sending button info to dropdown select function
        # btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: setattr(dropButton, "text", btn.text))
        # btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: select(dropButton, btn.text, btn))
        btn.bind(on_release=partial(select, dropButton, btn.text))

        # Closing drop down after selection
        btn.bind(on_release=dropdown.dismiss)

        # Adding buttons to the drop down
        dropdown.add_widget(btn)

    # Binding the button to a function that triggers the drop down
    dropButton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

    test_floatie.add_widget(dropButton)


# Running la app
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return test_floatie


MainApp().run()
```

Note the use of `partial` instead of the commented out `lambda`.
It looks like they accomplice the same thing, but they don't.. (see [here](http://discourse.techart.online/t/python-lambda-or-partial/4752))

> If you are creating callbacks in a loop, and using a loop variable as an argument for the callback, then you should use `partial`. `lambda` evaluates the variable at runtime, whereas `partial` evaluates when the `partial` function is created.